# Scrolling using Synaptics Forcepad choppy

Tags: touchpad

I have installed ELementary OS a couple of days ago, but there is a small problem I'm facing at the moment. I own an elitebook 1040 g1 which has a synaptics forcepad built in. In windows, scrolling and gestures work like a dream. In elementary though, it is a little choppy. Sometimes when I let go of scrolling and the page keeps scrolling, it becomes buttery smooth the second I let go of the trackpad. Is there anyone who can help me fix this?

Emiel